# ¿Se puede enviar parametros post en window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

es posible enviar parámetros `post` a un `window.location.href` al hacer click en un botón me envíe a una nueva página con parámetro `post`, no quiero enviarlo por `get` desde la `url`.

Comment: Lo has probado? cuál es tu código? Qué ha pasado?

Comment: He leído algunos foros, la manera es crear un form con javascript y luego hacer un submit a la pagin  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367979/pass-post-data-with-window-location-href

Answer (score 1):

Realmente el window.location.href hace referencia especificamente a la direccion de la pagina actual. El metodo POST se utiliza como uno de los metodos de enviar formularios y no se puede representar a traves de una URL. La forma de representar un formulario seria con el metodo GET. Te recomiendo que crees un formulario a javascript (document.createElement('form')) y le introduzcas los valores que deseas enviar y utilices la funcion submit implicita en los forms.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes enviar variables con windows.location.href, pero como otra opción puedes usar [**jquery.redirct.js**](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect) un plugin muy útil justo para lo que buscas, enviar post desde javascript sin necesidad de un formulario, acá te dejo la documentación https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect

Answer (score 0):

Sí:

Suponemos que el controller devuelve una vista(en un proyecto MCV Core):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(string val)
    {
        ViewBag.val = val;
        return View("Example");
    }
```

Que llamamos desde una funcion javascript con Jquey.POST, pasándole los opotunos parámetros

```
 $.post("http://Controller/Test",{ val: 1 }).done(function( data ) { $( "body" ).html(data);});
```

Y entonces recargamos body desde Jquery con el contenido de data (la parte final de la instrucción jquery)

```
(...) done(function( data ) { $( "body" ).html(data);});
```